# Infusionsoft File Box - Delete File

Tags: infusionsoft

I am new to the infusionsoft API and I am attempting to maintain some files in a Contacts' File Box...

According to the API documentation:

https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/File_Service

I can ADD a file
I can RENAME a file
I can REPLACE a file

There appears to be no way of deleting a file or getting a list of files with their details..

I want to be able to replace or delete previous file and upload a new one.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of the [data service](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Data_Service#delete) and interacting with [tables](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Table_Documentation)! Specifically, you're going to want to use `DataService.delete` to delete the file in the database. You can also use `DataService.query` to get File details.

Here's an example for deleting a file, via the PHP SDK:

```
$file_id = 123;
$deleted = $app->dsDelete( 'FileBox', $file_id );
```

That's it! You can do a LOT with the Data Service.

**EDIT:** It looks like the FileBox table only allows `Read` access...Silly. Completely deleting the file via the API appears to be impossible. Gold Star, InfusionSoft.

An alternative for "deleting" a file would be to replace the file contents with an empty string. Something like:

```
$file_id = 123;
$deleted = $app->replaceFile( $file_id, '');
```

Note that this won't actually delete the file entry from the table...

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I got all excited and then got this error back from the API... "[NoTableAccess]You cannot delete from FileBox through the API" - any idea if that's my access level or it's not possible?

Comment: Yep, you're right. On second glance of the FileBox table, it only allows `Read` access. Plain silly. The only other thing I can think of is to use `FileService.replaceFile` to replace the `Base64EncodedData` with an empty string.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of the second suggestion.

Comment: as you say. complete madness. I don't think the replace with an empty file is going to cut it with the customer... The requirement for me is to keep a list of Quote PDFs in the file box and when a quote turns into an Order I need to delete the original Quote PDF and upload the Order PDF... Im stuffed it looks like!!

Comment: Yep, totally stuffed. Looks like my answer will definitely not be adequate. Bummer!

Comment: for reference, this is a thread on the community forum... http://community.infusionsoft.com/showthread.php/16981-Managing-Files-through-API?p=43749#post43749

Comment: for my situation. I think I have come up with way around this. the PDF in the filebox with be named by OrderNumber. I can then create and replace them.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way of deleting files from the FileBox via the API. This was done intentionally to prevent files from accidentally being deleted.

Comment: Wait...to prevent people, who are using the API, from doing something simple? I don't get how you would "accidentally" run a `dsDelete` or `deleteFile` (if it existed). I think you're trying to prevent something that is a non-issue here.

Comment: `replaceFile` is arguably even more dangerous than a delete option would ever be, as it requires proper `Base64EncodedData`. Get that parameter wrong, and your original file is toast.

Comment: i have to agree with @mevius here... it does seem crazy that you can blat a file with the replaceFile but there is no way to delete a file..